# No such file or directory, but the files are there

Tags: c, linux, compilation, gstreamer, kdevelop

Im trying to compile a gstreamer plugin using Kdevelop in Kubuntu 12.04, but I get the following error:

```
gcc: error: /usr/lib/libgstvideo-0.10.so: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /usr/lib/libgstcontroller-0.10.so: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [libvpefTEMPLATE.la] Error 1
*** Failed ***
```

When I cd into /usr/lib/ The files ARE there, and they are not misspelled or anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `ldconfig`? You might also want to read [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Comment: have you tried ``ls -l`` and see if they aren't broken links?

Comment: I tried `ldconfig` but it still doesn't work. `ls -l` shows them pointing to something. `libgstvideo-0.10.so -> libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0`

Comment: @dead_jake Just because they are pointing to something doesn't mean that something exists. You can use the `file` utility to test whether a given link is broken or not.

Comment: Great! The links WERE broken because they were pointing to older versions that were deleted. I had to manually remove them and create new ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that helped me.

I `cd` into the folder then typed

```
file libgstvideo-0.10.so
```

and got

```
libgstvideo-0.10.so: broken symbolic link to `libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0'
```

I searched libgstvideo and saw that the current file was called libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.25.0 , so I did the following:

```
sudo rm libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0
sudo ln /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.25.0 ./libgstvideo-0.10.so
```

and repeated for the rest of the files. Thanks guys.